# How do I get started on Remmina?

Tags: remote-desktop, remmina

I will be giving my Dad a computer within the next couple of days, and I will need to set it up so that I am able to remotely administer it while he is at home 3,000km away.

I haven't used RDP etc before.

I discovered today that my computer already has Remmina installed, and I have a spare computer to test it all with before my Dad's new computer arrives.

I installed Remmina on the spare computer this morning.

I am able to start Remmina on either of these two computers.

I want to use the spare computer to control my main computer. On my main computer, I 'ifconfig' in a terminal and get the IP address 192.168.178.35.

- I start Remmina on the spare computer
- create a new connection
- leave the default connection name
- Protocol>RDP
- Server 192.168.178.35
- User el_gallo_azul (my account user name on the main computer)
- Password (I enter the password of my account on the main computer)
- Domain - leave blank because I don't know what's supposed to go here
- Click 'Connect'

This gives the error "Unable to connect to RDP server 192.168.178.35"

I have set my Desktop Sharing Preferences on my main computer to 'Allow to view' and 'Allow to control'.

I can't find any instructions on the internet.

This doesn't bode well for when I am trying to access a computer that isn't even on my home network.

Comment: The 'Desktop Sharing' in Ubuntu desktop is provided by a VNC server (`vino-server`) rather than an RDP server - try connecting your Remmina client using VNC protocol instead.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. It was actually your comment on ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2177810 that got me a little bit further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2177810](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2177810), I discovered that I should use a different protocol. I'm now using VNC, and once I discovered that I should accept the connection on my main computer, I got it to work. Now to figure out how do it over the internet... I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: I've had a look for methods to remotely connect over the internet **without** static IP address, dynamic dns or any installation on the client side, and the closest that I've found is TeamViewer, but I don't think that is going to work because of the client download (for an instance of support) being a .tar.gz file ([link]http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_qs.tar.gz)).